# Woocommerce showing the wrong price on listing page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Hello I have developed a woocommerce website, website working properly but in this have a bug on the home page showing different price and Detail page are show the different price 
see URL and attachment anyone help me
https://mediphyt.sg/

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: these products are showing by Visual Editor....

Comment: best selling product ??

Comment: no all products are same issue...

Answer (score 0):

That difference is about 6%, could it be one page is showing with tax and one without?

Comment: how to solve this issue....and show the same price on both places...

Comment: Hello 
on my website, woo-commerce product price is correct on desktop version but when opening on mobile view different price

Comment: This sounds like a different problem as your OP looks like it's desktop only screenshots. Are you on the same network on both devices? Could the mobile device be appearing from a different region so has different tax applied?